# How to access Clearance Shoulda macros in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, clearance

I can't work out how to get access to the shoulda macros (sign_in_as, etc) in my RSpec tests.  I've installed and unpacked the shoulda gem into vendor and I've run the generator to install clearance.  I suspect I need to use the right require statement in spec_helper.rb but nothing I've been able to find works for me.  I've completely run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to to the top of your spec_helper.rb,

```
require 'clearance/shoulda_macros'
```

And then inside the Rspec configure block add the following,

```
config.extend(Clearance::Shoulda::Helpers)
```

Comment: Hmmmm - I thought that was working but I'm still getting the following:  
undefined method `sign_in_as' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_2::Nested_8:0xb24ac9c>

Comment: Ok - I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but it's now behaving.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm getting a `require: no such file to load --clearance/shoulda_macros (LoadError)`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by following the instructions on this blog post: http://blog.smajnr.net/2011/03/clearance-rspec-shoulda.html

```
# in spec_helper.rb

require 'clearance/shoulda_macros'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # ...

  # Include Shoulda macros for Clearance
  config.include Clearance::Shoulda::Helpers
end
```